replace new in std::__cxx11::basic_string
In my app., most 'new' operator including 'delete' is replaced with ones of my own. but it shows some 'new' operator in "std::__cxx11::basic_string" is yet not replaced and it is still using the original one in GCC.
I cope GCC "new_op*" and compiled into object of my own. when linking, I put object of my own in ahead of GCC libstdc++.a.  It's expected that my 'new' operator would replace all the 'new' in GCC and system.

Welcome to Stackoverflow! It's impossible to help you without seeing what
you did. Edit your
post to include a Minimal Reproducible Example
